# How can create multiple pdf files using mpdf API

Tags: php, html, pdf, mpdf

How can create multiple pdf files using mpdf API.

When I try to create using mpdf i got the error message like

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class mPDF

```
$sql1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
{
    $Alert_date=$row['Alert_Mail_Date'];


    $cart_body='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>New Order Placed</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
    <td width="400" align="left" valign="top">
    <a style="font-size:16px"><strong>.$Alert_date.</strong></a><br />
    </body>
    </html>';

    include("APIs/mpdf/mpdf.php");
    // Define a new mPDF document using utf-8 fonts
    $mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8');
    $ran= rand(0,9999999);
    //$mpdf = new mPDF('ta',array(210,297)); //array(210,297) --> A4 Size..
    $mpdf->SetAutoFont(AUTOFONT_ALL,array(210,297));
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($cart_body);
     $filename="/opt/lampp/htdocs/Invoice/invoice_PDF/".$ran."test.pdf";
    $mpdf->Output($filename,'F');
    //$mpdf->Output();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error simply means you have a **class of the same name declared more than once**. Maybe via multiple includes. 
Use your `include` statement before the loop.

Also check out  [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php). It will save you next time.

Answer (score 0):

You keep redeclaring mpdf.
Instead declare it before your loop.

```
include("APIs/mpdf/mpdf.php");
$sql1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
{
    $Alert_date=$row['Alert_Mail_Date'];


    $cart_body='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>New Order Placed</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
    <td width="400" align="left" valign="top">
    <a style="font-size:16px"><strong>.$Alert_date.</strong></a><br />
    </body>
    </html>';


    // Define a new mPDF document using utf-8 fonts
    $mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8');
    $ran= rand(0,9999999);
    //$mpdf = new mPDF('ta',array(210,297)); //array(210,297) --> A4 Size..
    $mpdf->SetAutoFont(AUTOFONT_ALL,array(210,297));
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($cart_body);
     $filename="/opt/lampp/htdocs/Invoice/invoice_PDF/".$ran."test.pdf";
    $mpdf->Output($filename,'F');
    //$mpdf->Output();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can generate multiple pdfs using mpdf, you just need to put the pdf generation code inside a loop. The re-declaration of class error has occured because you must have started a new instance without closing the previous one. `$mpdf->Output` ends the instance. Try redefining the class after this statement.
Keep the `include("APIs/mpdf/mpdf.php");` outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to generate multiple PDF Files and save them in some directory.I used the sleep and time functions to generate unique filename so that it will overwrite existing file with same name.

```
<?php
$record = array('BMW','Mercedes','Toyota');
include_once("../lib/MPDF57/mpdf.php");
foreach($record as $value){
$filename = time().'Performance_review.pdf';
sleep(2);
$mpdf=new mPDF(); 
$mpdf->WriteHTML($value);
$get_pdf   = $mpdf->Output('../pdf-output/'.$filename,'F');
}?>
```